# How to use scala case classes when delegation is needed

Tags: naming, scala, data-types, trait, delegation

Let's assume in our application we want to model cars. We also want to model a car repository where we store some registered cars. How should that be modeled in scala?

Here comes my approach: First, I create a case class `PlainCar`. This is just a car how it exists in real world, with nothing special in it. Next I create a `CarRepository`. I also create a `RegisteredCar`. The `CarRepository` can now store `PlainCar`s and return them as `RegisteredCar`s. Both `PlainCar` and `RegisteredCar` extend the trait `Car` which provides all the comon methods like `drive`. `RegisteredCar` however is special - it owns an instance of `PlainCar` but also adds a method `registrationNumber` which returns the registration number; all other methods are just delegated to the `PlainCar` instance.

I feel however, that there are some flaws of this design. One is that I have to change `RegisteredCar` when I add a method/property to `PlainCar` which I think should not have to be done.

My question is therefore, can this be modeled better and if so, how? Are there other drawbacks that I am missing?

Some advice on naming conventions would also be appreciated because `PlainCar` sounds quite awkward to me.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if registration is a state which only has meaning in the context of a repository.  You have described two states, (registered with the repository, not registered with the repository).  It sounds to me as if what you need is a car container (wrapper if you like).  Think of it as a collection which can hold one car, in the same way that **Option[Car]** or **Either[Car, Motorbike]** can only hold one object.

So create a **RepositoryItem** sealed base trait (or sealed abstract class) and create case class instances (which extend RepositoryItem) for each state.  The Registered variant would have a registration number.  Make your **Repository** a container of **RepositoryItems**.  It should not be part of the same set of case classes.

Advantages of this approach include

- You can make it generic (**RepositoryItem[A]** or **RepositoryItem[+A]** rather than **RepositoryItem[Car]**).  This means it could become a repository of other things (or could easily expand to hold motorbikes as well as cars).
- Complete separation of concerns between repository implementation and car implementation.  One can change (or add new features) without affecting the other.
- You can create new subclasses of Car as often as you like.  Even if you create **Repository[Car]** from the start, rather than making it generic, it will be able to hold Car subclasses with no modification.

Have a look at the way **Option** and **Either** are designed.  You might want to implement at least **map**, so that you can manipulate a car (or replace it with a bike) without having to take it out of the repository slot.

**EDIT:**

To explain a point which may have created confusion, judging by your comment...

The **Option** and **Either** types have a **map** function (as does **List** and any other monad).  The map function allows you to pass in a function which can manipulate the object contained.  You get back a transformed object still wrapped in the Option.

```
scala> val o = Some(3)
o: Some[Int] = Some(3)

scala> o map (_ * 5)
res2: Option[Int] = Some(15)
```

No dependencies between **Option** and **Int** but because **Option** implements **map** you can manipulate the **Int** without removing it from **Option** wrapping.

Comment: Doesn't that mean, `Car` is coupled with `RepositoryItem`? So if I remove the whole repository-thing, I have to change `Car` because it cannot extend `RepositoryItem` anymore. I actually feel more comfortable when I am able to ship my `Car` class even to another project without having to touch it in any way and without having to deliver dependencies like `RepositoryItem`. But maybe I got you wrong, I am not sure. I get the advantage of having a generic repository though.

Comment: No.  Is **Option** coupled with **int** if you create an **Option[Int]**?  Is **List** coupled with **String** if you create a list of strings?  No coupling at all.  You seem to have completely misunderstood my point.  I said **container**, the same way an Option or a List is a container.  Cars can be added to those, and removed, without any coupling or redesign.  **Some(Car)** will return an **Option[Car]** with neither Option nor Car knowing anything about each other.

Comment: I missunderstood you here. But I still don't get why I should ever create the `NotRegistered(Car)` thing in my code. I always now, if I handle registered cars or if I handle with just plain ones. Different to Option, where I often/always not know if it is a Some or None. Also, where would the common car methods be implemented (with method body I mean) - in the sealed trait itself?

Comment: The common Car methods would go in the Car trait or class.  Whatever you call your principal car class, your car classes should not contain Repository details.  Whether a car is stored in a repository is not an intrinsic property of the car - it is a property of the repository.  Why should the parts of your code which know nothing about repositories have to be aware of repository registration numbers or the different repository-related states?  You say you are worried about coupling, but you seem determined to complicate the car class itself.

Comment: When I have a `Car` trait, the rest of my code will just work with `Car`, so it can work with all kind of cars as long as they are cars. But the code that needs to work with the registration will use `RegisteredCar` as it has to do checks like `carA.regNr == carB.regNr`. That means only the code that uses the registrationNumber will know about that `RegistratedCar` class. But from your answer, I see that that `RegisteredCar` class would not own a `PrincipalCar` and delegate to it, but the implementation of the methods would rather be in the common `Car` trait.

Comment: Yes.  Anything that cared about registration would have do deal with the container to get registration details and the car contained within for car things.  There are other ways to do this (e.g. Scala equivalents of the Decorator pattern), but case classes are the wrong choice.  Case classes are best used for significantly different, distinctly alternative variants of the same basic concept.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I'm missing something, but I would just make your `CarRepository` a `Map[RegistrationNumber, PlainCar]` or something similar.  Usually with immutable objects, it's much easier to create this kind of association outside the original object.

My second choice would be `RegisteredCar extends PlainCar`, but I think this creates unnecessary coupling and copies.  Both of those options would allow you to just rename `PlainCar` to `Car`.

Comment: Hi, the problem with the Map-approach is, that I want to give a registered car to a function and it should be aware, that this car is registered. I could also go for `someFunction(plainCar, registerNumber)` but naturally it feels better to group both these arguments into one object, because they belong together - and I called this object `RegisteredCar`. Extending `PlainCar` also came to my mind, but I have read in different places that extending a `case class` is not recommended.

Comment: @valenterry  But how much of your code cares about (or should know about) repositories?  What happens if you have to create some other context, in a different part of the code, which contains extra information or state about cars?  Will you add new case classes?  You couldn't, because those states would be orthogonal to repository states.

Comment: Well, most code will just work with the plain `Car`, but some code knows about that a car can be registrated and has to work with their registration number, so it will work with `RegisteredCar`. What do you mean by extra state? Like a second repository where cars can be registrated in?

Comment: Multiple repositories would be another reason for considering containers, but I was thinking of other domains with other concerns.  Imagine you want to track the insurance status and tax registration of cars; these are things which change (new regulations, changes n cost).  I don't think those states should be held in the car class.